# parseable git log output

Tags: git

You can customize the output of `git log` using `--pretty` and you can show the number of added and deleted lines using `--numstat`. It looks like this:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h - %ar : %s" --numstat config*.ini

f665c63 - 6 months ago : fixes session end post
1       1       config.ini

4541de2 - 7 months ago : fixes missing strings
6       1       config.ini
3       1       config_office.ini
```

But what I want is the output of both, the commit information and the changes in the files, to show in one line each. Something like this:

```
1       1       config.ini            f665c63 - 6 months ago : fixes session end post
6       1       config.ini            4541de2 - 7 months ago : fixes missing strings
3       1       config_office.ini     4541de2 - 7 months ago : fixes missing strings
```

This way it would be straightforward to parse this output using `grep`, `sort`, etc. Does git already provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `git log` can't do that natively. However, this sed command will do it:

```
sed '/^[0-9]\+\t[0-9]\+\t[^\t]\+$/ b file; h; d; : file; G; s/\n/\t/'
```

It looks for the `--numstat` lines. Any non-numstat line is copied into the hold buffer and not printed. Lines with numstat output get the current contents of the hold buffer appended, leaving a newline in the middle, which is then replaced with a tab.